# delete duplicate records in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

We have 2 tables called : "post" and " post_extra"

summery construction of "post" table's are: `id,postdate,title,description`

And for post_extra they are: `eid,news_id,rating,views`

"id" filed in the first table is related to "news_id" to the second table.

There are more than 100,000 records on the table, that many of them are duplicated. I want to keep only one record and remove duplicate records on "post" table that have the same title, and then remove the related record on "post_extra"

I ran this query on phpmyadmin but the server was crashed. And I had to restart it.

```
DELETE e 
FROM Post p1, Post p2, Post_extra e 
WHERE p1.postdate > p2.postdate 
  AND p1.title = p2.title 
  AND e.news_id = p1.id
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep entries with the lowest `id` for each `title`

```
DELETE p, e
FROM Post p
left join Post_extra e on e.news_id = p.id
where id not in
(
   select * from 
   (
      select min(id) 
      from post
      group by title
   ) x
)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46787/1)

Comment: i ran your code and i got this error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dle_post' p left join 'dle_post_extras' e on e.news_id = p.id where id not in' at line 2

Comment: I added a subquery. Now it works. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46787/1)

Comment: tnx juergen but i got above error again .i saw this work in sqlfiddle but why it didnt work in phpmyadmin

Comment: You are using quotes around your table name. Don't do that. If you want to escape a table or column name use backticks: `

Comment: thank you  query ran.but it decrease performance is there a better way?

Comment: i have a problem , the records in post_extras didnt remove how i solve this?

Comment: It works in the Fiddle. You probably did not correctly apply the example.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have table named as 'tables' in which you have the duplicate records.
Firstly you have to do group by column on which you want to delete duplicate.But I am not doing it with group by.I am writing self join instead of writing **nested query** or **creating temporary table**.

```
SELECT * FROM `names` GROUP BY title, id having count(title) > 1;
```

This query return number of duplicate records with their title and id.

You don't need to create the temporary table in this case.

To Delete duplicate except one record:
In this table it should have auto increment column. The possible solution that I've just come across:

```
DELETE t1 FROM tables t1, tables t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.title = t2.title
```

if you want to keep the row with the lowest auto increment id value OR

```
DELETE t1 FROM tables t1, tables t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.title = n2.title
```

if you want to keep the row with the highest auto increment id value.

You can cross check your solution,by selecting the duplicate records again by given query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tables` GROUP BY title, id having count(title) > 1;
```

If it return 0 result, then you query is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete duplicate record by creating a temporary table with unique index on the fields that you need to check for the duplicate value

then issue

Insert IGNORE into  select * from  TableWithDuplicates

You will get a temporary table without duplicates .

then delete the records from the original table (TableWithDuplicates) by JOIN  the tables

**Should be something like**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_post` (
`id` INT(10) NULL,
`postDate` DATE NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(50) NULL, UNIQUE INDEX `postDate_title_description`        (`postDate`, `title`, `description`) );

INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_post
SELECT id,postDate,title,description
FROM post ;

DELETE post.*
FROM post
LEFT JOIN tmp_post tmp ON tmp.id = post.id
WHERE tmp.id IS NULL ;
```

Sorry I didn't tested this code